# javascript / canvas5 error from simple code

Tags: javascript, html

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.11.1/test/canvas5_b.php :: setup :: line 27"  data: no]

```
function setup() {

    var e = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = e.getContext('2d');


    var meter = new Image();
    meter.src = "meter.jpg";
    var meter_bar = new Image();
    meter_bar.src = "meter_bar.jpg";
    //alert(meter);

    ctx.beginPath();/////////LINE 27////////////
    ctx.drawImage(meter, 50, 100);
    //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    ctx.drawImage(meter_bar, 68, 123);
    ctx.closePath();


}

window.onload = setup;
```

Both the images are in the right folder. The thing that gets me is that it works if you put a alert(meter); before line 27. Its as if it is not loaded, but I have it running on window.onload, so I dont see how that is.

edit : It is an issue of when the image is loaded (ty rob). It appears best to globally declare and set the image src, and then call window.onload = setup, like this : (correct me if this is bad)

```
var img1, img2;
img1 = new Image();
img2 = new Image();
//declare and set the images src
img1.src = "meter.jpg";
img2.src = "meter_bar.jpg";

var canvasHeight, canvasWidth;
canvasHeight = 300;
canvasWidth= 600;

var ctx;


function setup() {
    var e = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx = e.getContext('2d');
    draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 50, 100);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 68, 123);
    ctx.closePath();
}

window.onload = setup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the images are loaded first.  For instance:

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }

 // put this after onload, otherwise onload may 
 // not be called if image is in cache
 img.src = 'whatev.png';
```

Comment: I thought img.onload wouldnt fire after img.src, since its already loaded. Will have to test this.

Comment: I just rearranged it above to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the delay introduced by `alert` is enough to allow the image to load, but without `alert`, the images have not loaded in time. Try drawing the images onto the canvas only once they have loaded:

```
function setup() {

    function maybeDraw() {
        this.loaded = true;
        if(meter.loaded && meter_bar.loaded) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(meter, 50, 100);
            //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
            ctx.drawImage(meter_bar, 68, 123);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }

    var e = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = e.getContext('2d');

    var meter = new Image();
    var meter_bar = new Image();
    meter.onload = maybeDraw;
    meter_bar.onload = maybeDraw;
    meter.src = "meter.jpg";
    meter_bar.src = "meter_bar.jpg";

}

window.onload = setup;
```

Comment: Would maybeDraw be called 2 times? Or fail on the first try since the other image isnt loaded yet?

Comment: @jason: Yes, it would be called two times, but the if statement checks to see if both images have loaded. (When maybeDraw runs, it sets either `meter.loaded = true;` or `meter_bar.loaded = true;`, depending on which one it is.)

Comment: ahh i see what you did there. So what if theres a bajillion images to load.... Im thinking one way to do it would be set the biggest image to the last one loaded, and on its onload, call maybeDraw(), but I suspect that in some situations that wouldnt work, and its certianly not elegant.

Comment: @jason: In that case, I might consider incrementing a counter for every successful load, then once the counter reaches the number of images that must be loaded, draw the images onto the canvas.

Comment: Late last night I reached this conclusion! Great minds think alike!